# How do I import a public key that my friend stored in keybase.io into Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, enigmail, keybase

I want to encrypt my emails. Fortunately, my friend uploaded his public key to `keybase.io`.
I installed Thunderbird and Enigmail and uploaded my own public key. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be as easy to load the public key from `keybase.io` into Thunderbird/Enigmail.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Each user's profile page contains a link with their 16-digit PGP key ID:

[image]

Clicking it reveals a copy-pastable version of the public keyblock, as well as a link to it:

```
https://keybase.io/<username>/pgp_keys.asc
```

The key can be imported from a file using `gpg --import`, or *File → Import key from file* within Enigmail itself. You can also use *Edit → Import key from clipboard (or URL)* menu items.

If you have Keybase installed locally, `keybase pgp pull <username>` is also worth a try. I'm not sure whether it allows pulling any user's key, or only those you're following.

---

Additionally, the same Keybase key-information screen will show the full 20-digit "fingerprint", which you can use to look up keys on a traditional keyserver (if it has been uploaded there). The query should be the entire fingerprint without spaces. (Although other search terms also work, you'll want to verify the fingerprint *anyway*...)

Comment: Copy-pasting doesn't produce a file but gives you plaintext, can you be more exact about the steps involved?

Comment: Um, paste the key into a text editor (Notepad/gedit/Emacs/etc) and save it to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Go to First, click on the the key on `https://keybase.io/username`. Next you click on the 64-bit has of the key:

[image: 64 bit fingerprint on Keybase]

That brings up the dialog:

[image]

Right-click on `this key` and click `Save Link As...` to download the key-file.

Then you import the key in Kleopatra:

[image]